# Syntax Error in Sqlite manager

Tags: sqlite, sqlitemanager

hi I m using the following code to generate a table on sqlite manager.

```
CREATE TABLE Transaction (ID PRIMARY KEY , amount REAL , currencyCode CHAR(3) , comments VARCHAR , debitAccount INTEGER , creditAccount INTEGER , debitAccountExchangeRate REAL , creditAccountExchangeRate REAL , FOREIGN KEY (currencyCode)REFERENCES Currency (code) , FOREIGN KEY (debitAccount) REFERENCES Account  (ID) , FOREIGN KEY (parentAccount) REFERENCES Account (ID ));
```

but I am getting the syntax error. Can any one please specify what am i doing wrong here.

```
    [ near "Transaction": syntax error ]
    Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
      Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)      [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this..

```
CREATE TABLE "Transaction" (ID PRIMARY KEY , amount REAL , currencyCode CHAR(3) , comments VARCHAR , debitAccount INTEGER , creditAccount INTEGER , debitAccountExchangeRate REAL , creditAccountExchangeRate REAL , FOREIGN KEY (currencyCode)REFERENCES Currency (code) , FOREIGN KEY (debitAccount) REFERENCES Account  (ID) , FOREIGN KEY (creditAccount) REFERENCES Account (ID ));
```

Answer (score 4):

I was having a similar issue and, believe it or not, just changing my table name to "TRANSACTIONS" worked for me. "Transaction" must a reserved word in SQLite, but I know the error message I got was far from helpful.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error because I forgot to separate the columns in my query with commas. I guess it doesn't like that.

I was doing:

```
SELECT Col1 Col2 Col3 FROM Table1
```

SQLite was expecting:

```
Select Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM Table1
```